# Net MAUI Shell Menu with collapse inside sidebar

Tags: c#, maui, maui-community-toolkit, maui-windows

Hi i was wondering if it's possible to implement a collapsable menuitem with options inside the side bar.

like this:
[image]

I've tried using menuflyoutitem but it is only for tabbed menu I need a menu just like the one in the picture

Answer (score 1):

For this, you can create an animating Flyout Menu to display the menu that hides behind the Main Content.

For more information, you can refer to article [Fancy Flyout Menu](https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Blog/Post/xamarin-forms-fancy-flyout-menu) from Andrew. Although the article is based on Xamarin, the implementation is basically the same in MAUI.

The Fancy Menu utilizes a combination of `ContentPage`'s and `ContentView`'s to create the Flyout control instead of using the built in controls. Our control will be broken into 3 parts

- **Container** - Entry point of the Fancy Menu
- **Menu** - The hidden menu
- **MainContent** - The page that is initially rendered

Here,we just need to add the views we want to the Menu page.

The Menu page is a standard `ContentView` that displays the menu that hides behind the Main Content. Since the Container does all the heavy lifting all you need to do in this file is implement your menu. It will be styled correctly to take up the correct width and not overflow onto the Main Content.

You can refer to the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             BackgroundColor="SkyBlue"
             x:Class="FancyMenu.MenuPage">

    <ContentView.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalTextAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentView.Resources>
    
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Padding="{OnPlatform Android='50, 25', iOS='50, 50, 50, 25'}">
            <Label Text="Fancy Menu"
                   TextColor="White"
                   FontSize="30"
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Padding="10, 0, 10, 25">
            <Label Text="This is the fancy menu where youc an customize your control just like any page. I prefer to place header or profile content above the buttons, which is what this space is designed for." />
        </StackLayout>

        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Padding="25, 0, 25, 25" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="6*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Spacing="20"
                         VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <StackLayout.Resources>
                    <ResourceDictionary>
                        <Style TargetType="Frame">
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Lavender" />
                            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10" />
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15, 10" />
                        </Style>
                    </ResourceDictionary>
                </StackLayout.Resources>
                <Frame>
                    <Label Text="Home" />
                </Frame>
                <Frame>
                    <!--<Label Text="Settings" />-->
                    <Picker x:Name="picker"
                       Title="DropDown Menu">
                        <Picker.ItemsSource>
                            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                                <x:String>jQuery</x:String>
                                <x:String>Script</x:String>
                                <x:String>Net</x:String>
                            </x:Array>
                        </Picker.ItemsSource>
                    </Picker>
                </Frame>
                <Frame>
                    <Label Text="Contact" />
                </Frame>
                <Frame>
                    <Label Text="About" />
                </Frame>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                <Label Text="Hi" />
                <Label Text="Open Source Software" />
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
        
    </Grid>
    
</ContentView>
```

The result is:

[image]